# asp.net various caching options in BLL classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

What are all the caching options\levels possible in web-application BLL layer

(I understand we can use Session dictionary only in aspx and ascx code behind. right?)

Comment: This really is an open question. Session is perfectly available in a BLL layer as long as that BLL layer is part of an ASP.NET request. (Or something similar implementing Sessions). As for your question: There are massive amounts of caching possibilities available. Take a look at the new Caching support in the BCL. That might be a good place to start >> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985642.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is available as a storage medium at any level of an ASP.NET web app, however many of the classes involved in accessing it are sealed and not easily mockable (HttpContext, HttpSessionState, etc) and it is considered bad practice to have your business logic 'know' how your application is being hosted. I'd suggest hiding any cache implementations behind a generic ICache interface, which can then be easily switched out if you re-use your BLL in another application.

A few options available to you are:

A per request cache using HttpContext.Items (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx)

A session cache using HttpContext.Session (if your application is load balanced, and you do not have sticky sessions extra work must be done to ensure a consistent session state (eg using SqlSessionState)).

An application cache using HttpContext.Cache or HttpRuntime.Cache (again if your application is load balanced and you do not have sticky sessions extra work must be done to ensure a consistent application cache).

Hope this helps.